# Access edittext in TextWatcher

Tags: java, android

I have a textWatcher as TextChangeListener and I need to change the text from edittext.

My code is:

```
holder.txtResponder.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
   }

   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            holder.txtResponder.setText("I need change the text from this edit text but holder.txtResponder is not accessible");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why is it not accessible? If you declare it as `final` it should be accessible.

Comment: but holder.txtResponder canot be final, because It`s in a listview.

Comment: You can create a final reference to the `EditText`: `final EditText txtResponder = holder.txtResponder;`, unless there's something about your context that I don't understand.

Comment: dont even try this as "It is an error to attempt to make changes to s from this callback.", read TextWatcher docs